# MongoDB update query in array - object - array

Tags: mongodb

I'm making chat-app.
If i click chat-room , i want to change all chat
[{ ..., read: false => ..., read:true }]

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    
    ...

    chats: [{
        socketId: { type: String },
        receiverId: { type: String },
        receiverName: { type: String },
        chat: [{ 
            senderId: { type: String },
            senderName: { type: String },
            message: { type: String },
            time: { type: String },
            type: { type: String },
            read: { type: Boolean }
         }]
    }]
})
```

Find the chats[] with req.user._id and receiverId
I tried like this but it doesn't work

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.user._id, chats:{$elemMatch: {receiverId: req.body.receiverId }}},{
        "$set" :{
            "chats.$.chat": {
                "read": true
            }
        }})
```

Comment: Add document example in the question instead of the image. Also add expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updates all `read:false` to `read:true`

```
 User.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: req.user._id },
          { $set: { "chats.$[elem].chat.$[].read" : true } },
          {arrayFilters: [ { "elem.receiverId": req.body.receiverId } ],multi:true}
        )
```